# Issue with parentheses

Tags: tables, diagrams, ytableau

I'm stuck in two things:

1. How can I make the parentheses precisely fit the content. I used `\left(` and `\right)` but they seem bigger than whats in it.
2. I did my best to make the entry `(m)\gamma` appears smaller inside the box but I couldn't. Can anyone help me what should I do?

```
\[
\ytableausetup
 {mathmode}
M=\scriptstyle\left(\resizebox{.11\hsize}{!}{\begin{ytableau} {\scriptsize}
  & \none[\dots]
&\scriptstyle (m)\gamma &\\
 &\none[\dots]  &\\   
\none[\vdots]\\
 \\
\end{ytableau}}\scriptstyle\right)\]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `centertableaux` option to get the young diagram vertically centered.  It then turns out that the parentheses are a little too small, but one can correct this with the `\delimitershortfall`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ytableau,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \ytableausetup{mathmode,boxsize=2em,centertableaux}
  \setlength{\delimitershortfall}{-5pt}
  M=\left(
    \begin{ytableau}{\scriptstyle}
      &\none[\dots]&\scriptstyle (m)\gamma &\\
      &\none[\dots]&\\
      \none[\vdots]\\
      \\
    \end{ytableau}\right)
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```